# What's the meaning of "calculus" in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, ambiguity

Below paragrah is quoted from [here](https://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/):

> In the ***calculus*** of communication, writing coherent paragraphs that
>   your fellow human beings can comprehend and understand is far more
>   difficult than tapping out a few lines of software code that the
>   interpreter or compiler won't barf on.

I am not a native English speaker. I usually understand calculus as a mathematical area. And I cannot tell the difference between "calculus" and "computation". So maybe the above paragraph can reveal something about the deep meaning/implication of "calculus". For example, why the author doesn't choose "computation"?

Answer (score 1):

See [Oxford, 2nd definition: *A particular method or system of calculation or reasoning.*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/calculus)

The usage in the paragraph you cite seems a bit unusual, even for this definition.  It isn't about calculation in the usual sense.  It's  about applying an analytical context; thinking about communication in a way that allows you to compare the value or difficulty of things.

The author is saying that looking at communication in a certain analytical way, "writing coherent paragraphs that your fellow human beings can comprehend and understand is far more difficult than tapping out a few lines of software code that the interpreter or compiler won't barf on."

Comment: I'd agree that in the passage quoted, the use seems a bit odd even for the metaphorical extension of "calculus".  I suspect that "calculus" is often used in this context, without a clear meaning, simply to make the writing sound authoritative.  It's also probably influenced by the existence of another (partially related) more familiar word, "calculation".

Answer (score 1):

"Calculus" is often used in a somewhat figurative sense, derived from the secondary [definition:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/calculus)

> "A particular method or system of calculation or reasoning."

In fact, there are at least two such figurative definitions.  One is probably best translated as "a conspiratorial plot", or something of that nature -- the meaning is derived in part from the "calculating" nature of the participants.  But the other figurative sense is simpler and less pejorative (and closer to the dictionary definition) -- something like "a way of thinking about a topic."

The implication of this second figurative use is that the system being described is analogous to mathematics but much "softer", in that there are no equations or formulae and precious few "laws", in the strict sense.

The original quotation appears to be emphasizing that the "calculus" it is referring to is much "messier" than mathematics or computer programming.